# ActiveRecord 'where not' and 'where' in same query

Tags: sql, activerecord, sinatra

I would like to build a 'waiting_on' list where the users in the list meet two conditions: they do not belong to the current auction (`User.where.not(auction: @auction)`) and they do belong to the current_game `(User.where(game: current_game)`.

How can I populate the array `@waiting_on` with users who meet both these requirements in ActiveRecord?

#### Here's my pseudocode attempt:

`@waiting_on = User.where not(auction: @auction) and game: current_game`

#### Update:

At the moment I have got it working like this, but it is a little ugly:

```
users_in_auction = User.where(auction: @auction)
users_in_game = User.where(game: current_game)
@waiting_on = users_in_game - users_in_auction
```

I have been trying this: `User.where(game: current_game).where.not(auction: @auction)`, however the fact that the user that is not part of the auction has a `nil` value for `auction_id` seems to be messing it up. The SQL query output seemed to be exactly what I needed: `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."game_id" = 3 AND ("users"."auction_id" != 2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in one query by adding a null check:

```
User.where.not(auction: auction).or(User.where(auction: nil)).where(game: game)
```

This produces this SQL, which I think is what you want if I'm reading the question right:

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" 
WHERE (("users"."auction_id" != 7) OR "users"."auction_id" IS NULL) 
AND "users"."game_id" = 5
```

Comment: Sure thing, you bet!